# Can the paged pool memory limit can be increased?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, pagefile

We have a windows server 2003 R2 machine, 4GB RAM, 32 bit.

The paged pool limit is set to 354 MB. We have been having crashes twice in the last month and it is due to event ID : 2020 - The server was unable to allocate paged pool memory. We also confirmed the same using pagemon and other tools.

The question that I have is, is it advisable to increase the paged pool size (via setting in registry). I read a lot about these to be system set limits and advised not to change. 
We are on a 32 bit OS for now and hence I am thinking increasing the limit set is not a bad idea. But I am not very clear the consequences of this and is this something that is recommended ?

Thanks
Mani

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to find and resolve the cause of the paged pool exhaustion?

Comment: That's what we are attempting now. But I am curious to understand why not attempt to increase the limit.

Comment: Yes, you can increase it *slightly*.  Something like 650MB is the limit on 32bit Server 2003. PS - Get off of 32bit Server 2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on a Windows OS that is 10 years old. If you can, move to a 64-bit platform and/or fix the application/driver/whatever that is causing it. Have you identified what it is? [If not, here's some help on that score.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx)

If not, you're just trying to deal with the situation as-is. You can set it; it might not be able to be set much higher than you've already got. [In fact, your OS might already be configured for that to be dynamic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976157.aspx) and maybe [354 MB is the max you'll ever get.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/03/07/memory-management-understanding-pool-resources.aspx)

Also, if it's the kernel or a driver leaking the pool, it will always end up running out and you need to start doing prophylactic system reboots or fixing the root cause.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the link points to the choices. But I take your point on the 32 bit machines, I am fighting to get it replaced but we know how cost saving companies plan work !